# Sublime 3 autocomplete recommends vague internal functions in Julia

Tags: sublimetext3, julia

So I'm using Sublime Text 3 w/ Julia, and I have mixed feelings about the autocomplete. A lot of the time it recommends these vague internal functions that aren't even close to the word I'm typing in. For example:

http://puu.sh/iWyrB/7293a9928f.png

Even if I've used dict_t as a variable before, I have to type in most of the word before it recommends dict_t; it seems to happen once it runs out of internal functions to recommend.

So it seems like this is coming from the IJulia package. I like using that package, but moments like the picture above are frustrating. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

- To disable "insert completion on tab" add this to you User Preferences:

  ```
  // By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
  // This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
  // Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
  // ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
  "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
  ```
- To disable the auto-complete popup (but still be able to insert completion on tab):

  ```
  // Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.
  "auto_complete": true,
  ```

I'm afraid you cannot remove only the completions coming from Sublime-IJulia and keeping all default completions without changing any code in the Sublime-IJulia package.

---

If what you need is genera Julia support for sublime (syntax highlighting, auto-indent etc), I recommend switching from Sublime-IJulia to [Julia-sublime](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/Julia-sublime). Sublime-IJulia had it's last commit in January 2015 while Julia-sublime is actively maintained. Most notably in this case, Julia-sublime does not give autocomplete for all standard functions.

Note that Julia-sublime, like other syntax packages in sublime, does not not strive to be an IDE substitute. These features should be separated, not all users wants both.

For running Julia code from within Sublime with IDE-like functionality there is currently no good alternative, the packages I've found are outdated and have quite a few issues.

When it comes to developing and testing code, I like keep a REPL open in the terminal and just re-`include()` my code in there. I find this to be flexible and efficient. More on this in the Julia FAQ: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#how-can-i-modify-the-declaration-of-a-type-immutable-in-my-session).

*Disclosure: I am the maintainer of Julia-sublime. If you encounter issues or feel that something can be improved, I encourage you open an issue.*